# Using Pig's JsonLoader() with Json from Tweets

Tags: json, twitter, apache-pig

I am having a hard time with the parameters for the JsonLoader function of Pig. The Json object object is fairly large and the portion that is giving me the problem is everything within the "entities" field. If I take this out, I can get JsonLoader() to work fine. Could someone help me with the schema of this portion? Here is the Json of one tweet:

```
{
"contributors": null,
"truncated": false,
"text": "North Korea Says US 'Hell-Bent on Regime Change': North Korea says US 'hell-bent on regime change' and threate... http://t.co/FM4GhdQAcG",
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
"id": 452128135731884000,
"favorite_count": 0,
"source": "<a href=\"http://twitterfeed.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">twitterfeed</a>",
"retweeted": false,
"coordinates": null,
"entities": {
    "symbols": [],
    "user_mentions": [],
    "hashtags": [],
    "urls": [
        {
            "url": "http://t.co/FM4GhdQAcG",
            "indices": [
                114,
                136
            ],
            "expanded_url": "http://abcn.ws/1jb6ANh",
            "display_url": "abcn.ws/1jb6ANh"
        }
    ]
},
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"id_str": "452128135731884033",
"retweet_count": 0,
"in_reply_to_user_id": null,
"favorited": false,
"user": {
    "follow_request_sent": null,
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "id": 1484045802,
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/450180280033091584/ukwF1xQ1.jpeg",
    "verified": false,
    "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/450177921198465024/5EbZX19P_normal.jpeg",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "followers_count": 178,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
    "id_str": "1484045802",
    "profile_background_color": "FF3333",
    "listed_count": 0,
    "is_translation_enabled": false,
    "utc_offset": -10800,
    "statuses_count": 2900,
    "description": "Unico Menor Con Flow Mi Watsshat 18297015049",
    "friends_count": 103,
    "location": "santo domingo",
    "profile_link_color": "FF3333",
    "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/450177921198465024/5EbZX19P_normal.jpeg",
    "following": null,
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1484045802/1396166038",
    "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/450180280033091584/ukwF1xQ1.jpeg",
    "name": "Nïñø Mälø",
    "lang": "es",
    "profile_background_tile": true,
    "favourites_count": 2,
    "screen_name": "YeralMueka",
    "notifications": null,
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com/YeralMueka",
    "created_at": "Wed Jun 05 04:41:09 +0000 2013",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "time_zone": "Santiago",
    "protected": false,
    "default_profile": false,
    "is_translator": false
},
"geo": null,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
"possibly_sensitive": true,
"lang": "en",
"created_at": "Fri Apr 04 16:58:42 +0000 2014",
"filter_level": "medium",
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
"place": null
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Please read [this blog post on how to write good questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), and pay special attention to the "Golden Rule". The clear and more specific you are, the more likely you are to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elephant-bird library by twitter: https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird

Here is an example loading a JSON without specifying a schema using their custom JsonLoader: https://gist.github.com/neilkod/2898455

Answer (score 0):

I too worked with twitter tweets and from that I am aware of the fact that sometimes tweets vary in fields(some tweets contain addition fields than others) i.e., tweets are unstructured. You can use JsonLoader in pig if your input is structured...or else you can't do it...So to process it just define your own udf in pig to do it..To create udf in pig,follow the below link

```
           http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/udf.html#udf-java
```